# To Convert UIImage's into video format using FFmpeg libraries in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to develop an application in iPhone 3g of video recording and for that i'm using FFmpeg library i'm able to compile it but unable to get the code for this.
Can anyone help me in solving the problem?
If possible can anybody help me through code or any link to github or like that?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the FFMpeg source code here:

http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Either use svn:

```
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
```

or git:

```
git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/
cd ffmpeg
git clone git://git.ffmpeg.org/libswscale/
```